Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous and $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be bounded. Is $f(A)$ bounded?

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous and $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be bounded. Is $f(A)$ bounded?

If $f$ were continuous only on $A$, there would be a trivial counterexample in $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ with $A = (0,1)$; however, this function is obviously not continuous on $\mathbb{R}$. The above statement should be true because otherwise $f$ would need to approach $\pm\infty$ for an $x \in A$, which is impossible, since $f|_A$ is also continuous.
However, I am having issues proving that $f$ needs to approach $\pm\infty$ - intuitively it is clear, but I don't know how to formally write a proof.

Hint: if $A$ is bounded, then the closure of $A$ is compact.

@CJDowd Thank you! If we call $\bar{A}$ the closure of $A$, then I assume the proof is already complete after $\bar{A}$ compact $\implies$ $f(\bar{A})$ compact $\implies$ $f(\bar{A})$ bounded, along with $f(A) \subseteq f(\bar{A})$?

Does this answer your question? Continuous image of bounded set is bounded It was easy to find: https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=Continuous+image+of+bounded
